# Foreign keys in rails model generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to generate a model in rails that contains foreign keys with cascading delete?  I want to have a model "game" that has two users attached to it based on the two users playing.  How do I create those two users as foreign user objects so they will a) load when I load the game object, and b) automatically be deleted if one of the users is deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

And your game model:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user1, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user1_id"
  belongs_to :user2, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user2_id"
end
```

Comment: Also, remember that the `:dependent => :destroy` bit will work for destroy, not delete. If you really want it to work for deletes, you'll probably need to write a trigger if your data store supports it.

Comment: would these relationships go before or after the attr_accessible definitions.  I'm brand new to ruby and rails.  So forgive me if that's a stupid question.

Comment: I don't think that it makes much of a difference. However you would want to order it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use database foreign keys you can use:

https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner

use is like:

```
add_foreign_key(:games, :users, :column => 'user1_id', :dependent => :delete)
add_foreign_key(:games, :users, :column => 'user2_id', :dependent => :delete)
```